# Sublime tabs indentions are sorrounded with white border or rectangle

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I was wiping my keyboard when suddenly my sublime text 3 turn my tabs into this weird rectangles with white borders around it. I love it but how do I turn it off, I toggled it accidentally. As far as I can remember, I don't have plugins to make it look that way.

[image]

This may be useful, because you can see if your codes aligned very well and if tags have partners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already got the answer! It's a simple hack, `ctrl + f` then on the search bar just hit tab, so it finds all your tab indents. See that red outline in the image below, this is cool!

[image]

So if someone right there doesn't have the same result as mine, it's probably your whitespace are `spaces` and not `tabs`. You need to convert your spaces to tabs first. Then try just what I did. See that image above with blue outline on it, you can convert your spaces to tabs right there